# ECLemma, sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, eclemma

Thanks in advance.

I was trying code coverage using ECLemma eclipse plugin. Able to generate the reports on local system.Is there any way we can generate the reports on sonarqube server by changing the properties file..Here is my properties file that i am trying..

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.projectKey=org.accenture.sonarplugin
sonar.projectName=Code Analysis Plugin
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.junit.reportsPath=code-analysis-rules/target/surefire-reports/code-analysis-rules
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=code-analysis-rules/target/jacoco/Desktop.exec
sonar.sources=src

sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.profile=Sonar way

sonar.android.lint.report=lint-report.xml

sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
sonar.login = admin
sonar.password = admin*emphasized text*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a way to import these results simply by updating your properties values. You should, however, take a look at the [Generic Coverage](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage) plugin. Get your coverage data into this format and you'll be able to import it regardless of its origin.

Comment: Thank you Ann for your reply.